# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Replication. "The process could not connect to Subscriber".

Tags: replication, database-replication

Trying to get replication to work on MSSQL 2008, I am getting "The process could not connect to Subscriber" when viewing the synchronization status.
That happens on both of the servers defined on the replication (P2P replication).

I have went over the procedures of defining the replication over and over again, watched many video tutorials, but it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Thank you!